# Stop event firing on page load

Tags: jquery

I have added the following to a dynamically loaded image wrapped inside an anchor:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.adv_standard_d a img[alt="Youth Activity Fund Normanton"]', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
pwebContact207.toggleForm(1);  });
```

Which stops the anchor redirecting and initiates a modal pop up. However when the page is loaded in a clean browser the modal is also triggered. How can I stop the event from firing on page load?

Answer (score 0):

try to use **document ready**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on('click','.adv_standard_d a img[alt="Youth Activity Fund Normanton"]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pwebContact207.toggleForm(1);  
    });
});
```

Comment: No unfortunately that made no difference, thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Yes, there wasn't an issue with the code above, the issue was being caused by another script firing the modal on page load. Removed that and voila!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! Turns out the modal was being fired by something else completely!